# Google SSL security

Tags: ssl

I need to implement some search functionalities in my app and want to use Google SSL.

https://encrypted.google.com

Can the ISP still see what you are searching by analyzing the querystring? If so then what's the point of this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `SSL` (https) all traffic including the query string is encrypted. All that ISP can see is host address and TCP port number. If the page that you are viewing contains insecure content (http) you should be warned by your browser.